# Share Point task list email notifications

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, email

I created the workflow in sharepoint designer using Collect data from user option. The approver receives three automated mail.

1) Notification to approve - Task assigned email 2) After approval, task has been changed alert 3) Another task has been changed alert

Is there an option to suppress the last two task has been changed alert? I would like to send only the Task assigned mail to approver

Answer (score 2):

You can switch of alerts and set `E-Mail Notification` to `Yes` under your `Workflow Tasks list > Settings > Advanced Settings`. By doing so user specified in AssignedTo will receive e-mail notification when task is created and if task ownership is not changed during your workflow this will be the only mail sent by system.

Since you are already using SharePoint designer you also have option to include `Send an Email action` in your workflow (after task is created). This option is better if you want to send some specific info to user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to prevent an email being sent when the option to send emails to the owner is turned on, but the alternative solution would be to turn that option off and then create your own email alerts as part of the workflow. Don't know if you need that on to cover scenarios not mentioned here.