# How can you create a Task Notifications Workflow in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

How can you create a Task Notifications Workflow in SharePoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Point task list email notifications](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17518/share-point-task-list-email-notifications)

Comment: which version of SP you use??

Answer (score -1):

by this [article](https://spnotifications.codeplex.com) after install this wsp you have a list named notification that if item created in it your online users get notifications like this

[image]

you can create workflow in every lists that you want with this [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-workflow-f6a92a4b-c919-40d7-9728-2e79c524764c) like this .

[image]

when item added to list item create in notification list and prompt shows up

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77037)

Comment: @gaurravs = i'm editing and rewrite this answer.